# Same Countdown in different TimeZone - Swift

Tags: swift, calendar, timezone, countdown

I have already create a countdown that's working fine on CEST time zone, but I want that will show the same correct time remaining in all the countries with different Time Zone.

Any idea on how can I manipulate the code?

```
 // here we set the current date
    let date = NSDate()
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .month, .year, .day], from: date as Date)

    let currentDate = calendar.date(from: components)

    let userCalendar = Calendar.current

    // here we set the due date. When the timer is supposed to finish
    let competitionDate = NSDateComponents()
    competitionDate.year = year
    competitionDate.month = month
    competitionDate.day = day
    competitionDate.hour = hour
    competitionDate.minute = minute
    let competitionDay = userCalendar.date(from: competitionDate as DateComponents)!

    //here we change the seconds to hours,minutes and days
    let competitionDayDifference = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute], from: currentDate!, to: competitionDay)


    //finally, here we set the variable to our remaining time
    let daysLeft = competitionDayDifference.day
    let hoursLeft = competitionDayDifference.hour
    let minutesLeft = competitionDayDifference.minute

    print("day:", daysLeft ?? "N/A", "hour:", hoursLeft ?? "N/A", "minute:", minutesLeft ?? "N/A")
```

Comment: Where are the variables `year`, month`, `day` etc from?

Comment: This code is wrapped in a function, so Year, Month, Day etc are Int

Comment: Which timezone are the `year`, `month`, `day`, `hour` and `minute` in?

Comment: CEST TimeZone, so basically I will wish that it will maintain the same time left in all the other TimeZones

Comment: Can you show me what to modify in specific? Please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code doesn't work because the competition day is not represented by a *point in time* (x seconds since 1970), but as a *local date time* (year, month, day, hour, minute etc) instead.

To represent the competition date as a point in time, you need to associate it with a timezone, which you haven't provided. You can provide one to the `Calendar` that you use to get the `Date` from the date components:

```
var userCalendar = Calendar.current
userCalendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "...")!
```

And then the competition date will be converted to the same point in time no matter what timezone the device is in.

Alternatively, set `competitionDate.timeZone`:

```
competitionDate.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "...")!
```

Comment: That's brilliant! I haven't thought about this... Thank you very much :)

Comment: Better use UTC/GMT. Compare https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimezone/1387248-init (emphasis added): *In general, you are **discouraged from using abbreviations** except for unique instances such as “GMT”. **Time Zone abbreviations are not standardized** and so a given abbreviation may have multiple meanings—for example, “EST” refers to Eastern Time in both the United States and Australia.*

Comment: @MartinR The OP shouldn't use UTC/GMT because the given year/month/day/hour/minute is not in UTC/GMT. OP should use whatever timezone the given date is in, so I guess I'll let OP choose a timezone identifier.

Comment: @Sweeper: I just wanted to remark that `TimeZone(abbreviation: "CEST")` is not a good choice (and why). If the final date is retrieved from a server  then  I would probably make the server generate  a Unix timestamp.